# If a function is in L2, does its derivative have limit at infinity?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a twice differentiable function $f : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^n$, if $\int_{0}^{\infty} |f(s)|^2 ds < \infty$, does that imply $\lim_{s \to \infty} f'(s) = 0$ where $f'$ is $\frac{df}{ds}$ and $|\cdot|$ represents the Euclidean norm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider the function
$$
f:[0, \infty ) \longrightarrow R \\
f(s)=\frac{\sin(e^{s})}{s+1}
$$
It is smooth and $L^2$.
Its derivative is

$$
\frac{d f}{d s} = \frac{e^{s} \cos{\left(e^{s} \right)}}{s + 1} - \frac{\sin{\left(e^{s} \right)}}{\left(s + 1\right)^{2}}
$$
Which limit $s\longrightarrow\infty$ does not exist. This can be generalized to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Perhaps you are more interested in Sobolev spaces.